# How to render an interactive globe/earth for the iPhone OpenGL ES?

Tags: iphone, opengl-es

I am looking for an example that renders an interactive earth similar to the one in the [Smule](http://www.smule.com/) products.

Comment: Related non ES: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9511499/seam-issue-when-mapping-a-texture-to-a-sphere-in-opengl || http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17488259/opengl-mapping-texture-to-sphere The name of this operation appears to be "UV mapping": https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UV_mapping

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Someone just pointed me to this question.  I have one!

It's called WhirlyGlobe and it's built specifically for this purpose.  Runs on ios, uses a combo of Objective-C and C++ and is very Cocoa Touch friendly.  Uses delegates for camera motion, multithreaded, all that good stuff.

Oh, and it's freely available under the Apache2 license.

Details can be found here:
http://mousebird.github.io/WhirlyGlobe/

Comment: If you prefixed http://, it would make that URL clickable like this: http://mousebirdconsulting.com/whirlyglobe :p

Comment: the link is dead :( For anyone who is looking for it: https://github.com/mousebird/WhirlyGlobe/

Comment: The link's fine.  Must have been temporary.

Answer (score 3):

I can't offer any samples, but Dragon Forged Software sells a prepackaged OpenGL ES Globe for the iPhone. http://dragonforged.com/consult.shtml

Answer (score 2):

A company name Clever Coding offers a opengl implementation of a 3D globe for sale at http://www.clevercoding.com/iPhone3Dglobe.php