# Can you integrate Google Earth in your iOS app?

Tags: ios, google-earth

May be in a UIWebView, can you show the interactive Globe of Google Earth using its APIs?

How much control would I have to restrict various things like zoom level, flying from one destination to other etc?

Is there a direct API that I can use in my code?

Thanks
Dev.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK this is not possible - the google earth plugin is not supported by mobile Safari.
So, no there is no API that you can use...

Answer (score 1):

Slightly off topic, but there are other toolkits you can use to implement a 3D interactive globe on ios.  Check this thread.  [How to render an interactive globe/earth for the iPhone OpenGL ES?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/322111/any-one-know-of-an-opengl-es-example-of-an-interactive-globe-earth-for-the-iphone)