# How do I create a spinning globe with points of interest for an iPhone app?

Tags: iphone, ios, opengl-es, cocos2d-iphone

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Any one know of an OpenGL ES example of an interactive globe/earth for the iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/322111/any-one-know-of-an-opengl-es-example-of-an-interactive-globe-earth-for-the-iphon)

I'd like to build an app with a spinning 3d globe and a few points of interest on, which the user can interact with (zoom in, click on point of interest, turn and stop globe etc). I've seen an example of how to build a sphere using OpenGL ES and Cocos2d-iPhone (neither of which I have any experience with) but I wondered if this is the best approach, as both the examples I found seem to have no user interaction enabled.

What I would like is for someone to advise me the best way of building this? Should I use OpenGL ES or Cocos2d-iPhone or is there some other way that's better (considering I'd like the user to interact with it)?

I have the co-ordinates I need, but I'm unsure how I would even go about mapping them onto a sphere. Should I use a textured Image on the Globe? And then how would I go about adding the interaction>

Any advice would be really useful as I seem to be going round in circles with this (pardon the pun).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: There are a few other questions on the topic: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bopengl-es%5D+%2Bglobe , but I think the above has some of the best drop-in resources for creation of such a globe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks Brad - eventually we found this link which provides the source  - which is pretty cool (and free), so thought I should share:

http://www.scoop.it/t/ios-developing/p/628999997/whirlyglobe-for-ios

Comment: Congrats on the fix!  When you are able, please make sure to mark your answer as 'accepted' so other will see your question has been answered and be able to learn from your solution.  Cheers~

Comment: If you are running on XCode7+ then set the root ViewController of Window. Goto MainWindow.xib. Select Window scene and its Connections Inspector. From Outlet, rootViewController drag and drop to Delegate controller. This fixes the crash issue.

Comment: I implemented this sdk in my app, its simple